# Plotting estimated probabilities from binary logistic regression when one or more predictor variables are held constant

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am a biology grad student who has been spinning my wheels for about thirty hours on the following issue. In summary I would like to plot a figure of estimated probabilities from a glm binary logistic regression model i produced. I have already gone through model selection, validation, etc and am now simply trying to produce figures. I had no problem plotting probability curves for the model i selected but what i am really interested in is producing a figure that shows probabilities of a binary outcome for a predictor variable when the other predictor variable is held constant.

I cannot figure out how to assign this constant value to only one of the predictor variables and plot the probability for the other variable. Ultimately i would like to produce figures similar to the crude example i attached [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6gcZ.jpg). I admit I am a novice in R and I certainly appreciate folks' time but i have exhausted online searches and have yet to find the approach or a solution adequately explained. This is the closest information related to my question but i found the explanation vague and it failed to provide an example for assigning one predictor a constant value while plotting the probability of the other predictor. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-September/253899.html

Below i provided a simulated dataset and my progress. Thank you very much for your expertise, i believe a solution and code example would be helpful for other ecologists who use logistic regression.

The simulated dataset shows survival outcomes over the winter for lizards. The predictor variables are "mass" and "depth".

```
x<-read.csv('logreg_example_data.csv',header = T)
x
 survival      mass depth
1         0  4.294456   262
2         0  8.359857   261
3         0 10.740580   257
4         0 10.740580   257
5         0  6.384678   257
6         0  6.384678   257
7         0 11.596380   270
8         0 11.596380   270
9         0  4.294456   262
10        0  4.294456   262
11        0  8.359857   261
12        0  8.359857   261
13        0  8.359857   261
14        0  7.920406   258
15        0  7.920406   258
16        0  7.920406   261
17        0 10.740580   257
18        0 10.740580   258
19        0 38.824960   262
20        0  9.916840   239
21        1  6.384678   257
22        1  6.384678   257
23        1 11.596380   270
24        1 11.596380   270
25        1 11.596380   270
26        1 23.709520   288
27        1 23.709520   288
28        1 23.709520   288
29        1 38.568970   262
30        1 38.568970   262
31        1  6.581013   295
32        1  6.581013   298
33        1  0.766564   269
34        1  5.440803   262
35        1  5.440803   262
36        1 19.534710   252
37        1 19.534710   259
38        1  8.359857   263
39        1 10.740580   257
40        1 38.824960   264
41        1 38.824960   264
42        1 41.556970   239

#Dataset name is x 
# time to run the glm model
model1<-glm(formula=survival ~ mass + depth, family = "binomial", data=x)
model1
summary(model1)
#Ok now heres how i predict the probability of a lizard "Bob" surviving    the winter with a mass of 32.949 grams and a burrow depth of 264 mm
newdata<-data.frame(mass = 32.949, depth = 264)
predict(model1, newdata, type = "response")
# the lizard "Bob" has a 87.3% chance of surviving the winter
#Now lets assume the glm. model was robust and the lizard was endangered,
#from all my research I know the average burrow depth is 263.9 mm at a  national park 
#lets say i am also interested in survival probabilities at burrow depths of 200 and 100 mm, respectively
#how do i use the valuable glm model produced above to generate a plot 
#showing the probability of lizards surviving with average burrow depths stated above 
#across a range of mass values from 0.0 to 100.0 grams??????????
#i know i need to use the plot and predict functions but i cannot figure out how to tell R that i 
#want to use the glm model i produced to predict "survival" based on "mass" when the other predictor "depth" is held at constant values of biological relevance
#I would also like to add dashed lines for 95% CI
```

Comment: I cannot tell from your description and the linked hand-drawn diagram whether you expect the relationship of the three curves to be "parametric".   Are their differences supposed to be described by one or two parameters or are they separate curves that do not share any sort of generalized "shape"? And I have no clue what the "lizard-Bob" might refer to,  or even how a non-named lizard might enter into this problem. Do try to remember that we do not share your working area and you may (... no, you definitely) need to describe your research if we are to have a chance of understanding this data.

Comment: After looking at the answer from Ted Harding, one of the most respected regular responders to R help, that you criticised as "vague", I can only observe that _your_ question is only slightly less vague than that of that questioner from 7 years ago. At least you presented data. But data is NOT enough. Statistical consultation requires a substantive description of the background for the question.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and apologize for the poor description of my question. I am simply looking for code to plot predictive curves for a logistic regression model with 2 predictor (explanatory variables) when one of the predictors is held to a constant value specified by me.

Comment: Why would you think there would be curves with multiple inflection points with a model that had a RHS of `mass + depth`?

Comment: I believe it was vague to me because i am grossly inexperienced, i meant no offense whatsoever and am grateful for anyone who takes the time to help others! Clearly, the answer lies within Ted Hardings post which makes me even more frustrated with myself that i cannnot figure it out. I have been agonizing this for several days and believe my frustration got the best of me. I will be more thoughtful and respectful in the future when linking to work of others

Comment: The hand drawn diagram is simply to illustrate the type of figure i hoped to produce. The data i shared is simulated and I am not looking for statistical consulting or help with inference/interpretation. I am specifically looking for code to plot the prediction curve for one predictor variable while the other is held constant. I provided the data and code in the hope someone would have experienced a similar objective....

Comment: The `visreg` package might be what you are after with regards to plotting the results of your regression (while holding specific covariates constant). See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg/visreg.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks@conrad-mac I will give it a try and see if I can figure it out